# Swap undefined value with empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I have a parse method in a backbone app that builds a JSON object out of an array, however if a value is empty, it is written as undefined, which breaks the behavior of other methods, I need to set undefined values as empty strings and am having trouble doing that, any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: in this case I am trying to set the value of value: to an empty string if obj[key] = undefined

code:

```
 parse: function(data){
    return data.map(function(obj){
      var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
      return {
        attribute: key,
        value: obj[key]
      };
   });
 }

toQueryString: function(){
  var obj = this.toQueryData(),
    qs = [];
  for (key in obj) {
    qs.push(key + "=" + obj[key]);
  }
  return qs.join('&')
},
toQueryData: function(){
  return this.reduce(function(memo, model){
    memo[model.get('attribute')] = model.get('value');
    return memo
  }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the object has the property - key.

```
  value: obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] != undefined ? obj[key] : ""
```

//   or you could write it like this (which I prefer, think the bracket syntax is a little bit uglier):

```
   value: obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj.key != undefined ? obj.key : ""
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: hmm, I have tried this, yet it is still assigning an undefined value to value:

Comment: Now I check for undefined value also.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary condition:

```
value: obj[key] ? obj[key] : ""
```

Or (as pointed out by @Derek朕會功夫),

```
value: obj[key] || ""
```

Comment: Or equivalently `obj[key] || ""`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 -- Yep - Idk why, but I always forget about the `||` in these situations.

Comment: I have edited my question, after attempting your answer, I am still getting an undefined value

Answer (score 1):

Since your using backbone you could use underscores [**`defaults`**](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) method:

```
return _.defaults({attribute: key, value: obj[key]}, {value: ''});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toQueryString: function(){
  var obj = this.toQueryData(),
    qs = [];
  for (key in obj) {
    qs.push(key + "=" + (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj.key != undefined ? obj.key : ""));
  }
  return qs.join('&')
}
```

This ended up being the solution, thanks Marko!